# The @article parameter value must be 'all' for immediate_sync publications

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a publication of 4 tables and many subscribers (transactional push replication), most of them being interested by one of those 4 tables.

Everything is working fine as long as I create the subscription for all articles:

```
EXEC sp_addsubscription 
    @publication = @publicationName,
    @subscriber = @subscriber,
    @destination_db = @DatabaseName,
    @subscription_type = N'push',
    @article = 'all';
```

But I get an error if I change

```
@article = 'TableName'
```

**The @article parameter value must be 'all' for immediate_sync publications.**

Why this happens? How can I create a subscription only for one of those 4 tables (=4 articles)?

Comment: Memory says the solution to this type of problem is to separate the publication into the smallest subscribable chunks necessary (one table per publication in this case). I could be wrong.